# exclusion and inclusion not working in maven assembly plugin

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

In my project I have two classes **Test1.java** and **Test2.java**, my intention is to build two jars in such a way that **test1.jar** should contains only **Tets1.java** and **test2.jar** should contains only **Tets2.java**.

I have added exclusion and inclusion in maven assembly plugin but it seems not working, in both the jars I am able to see **Test1.java** and **Test2.java**

my **pom.xml** is given below

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-a</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>Test2.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <includes>
                            <include>Test1.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.example.MyMain</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <finalName>test1.jar</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assembly</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-b</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>Test1.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <includes>
                            <include>Test2.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.example.MyMain</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <finalName>test2.jar</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assembly</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**UPDATED VERSION (pom.xml)**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-a</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/Test.*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/Test1.*</include>
                        </includes>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.example.MyMain</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <finalName>test1.jar</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assembly</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-b</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/Test.*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/Test2.*</include>
                        </includes>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.example.MyMain</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <finalName>test2.jar</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assembly</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Normally jars are containing  `.class` files.

Comment: @PeterMmm yes when I extract the jar files I got both the class file `Test1.class` and `Test2.class`

Comment: Could you edit your question with the last version of your pom.xml, including @Mureinik advice ?

Comment: @ToYonos I have updates my answer with the latest pom.xml

Answer (score 3):

`<include>` and `<exclude>` are path elements, so you need to specify the whole path (or some wildcards), not just the filename. E.g.:

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>**/Test2.*</exclude>
</excludes>
<includes>
    <include>**/Test1.*</include>
</includes>
```

Comment: I tried this also but still when i extract the jar file I got to see both the class file `Test1.class` and `Test2.class`

Comment: @AlexMan well, the inclusion/exclusion was on the source `.java` files, not the `.class` files. If you you want to apply to them, you can use the `.class` suffix, or a wildcard like I did in my edited answer.

Comment: I tried that also still no luck...., do we need to specify the packagae

Answer (score 2):

You should use a custom `assembly.xml` file.

Example for `test1.jar` :

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
  <id>test1.jar</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
       <directory>src/main/java/</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/Test2.*</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <includes>
            <include>**/Test1.*</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

And in your `pom.xml` replace :

```
<descriptorRefs>
    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
</descriptorRefs>
```

with :

```
<descriptors>
    <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
</descriptors>
```

Comment: but I am having tow jars right , `test1.jar` and `test2.jar`. When I do this then it will be effected to both the jars

Comment: Indeed. I think you need to create custom `assemble.xml` file.

Comment: Documentation : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html

Comment: @ToTonos Can you give me a sample example based on my pom

Comment: So where in which location I need to place this `assembly.xml`

Comment: Same folder than `pom.xml`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147061/discussion-between-alex-man-and-toyonos).

Comment: I am getting  Descriptor with ID 'test1-assembly.xml' not found